# I am trying to make a Django project in PyCharm but am having the following problem

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am trying to make a Django project. I don't know why but Pycharm does not recognize any files that i put in it like database files, excel files, etc. All the files that i tried are registered in the Files Opened in Associated Applications and they are not in the Text files or the Ignored files. There is an question mark beside the file. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Your problem sounds more like a PyCharm support question than a Python Django programming problem. If you'd still like to see if people here can help, you should probably update the tags on your question and provide a bit more information. What file types are we talking about, what does the problem look like exactly?

Answer (score 0):

you should create a pycharm project before creating your django project, then when you create the django project you need to save it in your pychram directory you create

Comment: I have created a pycharm project. After that I installed Django and started building my wed application. But then i made a SQL database file but there is question mark beside and I can't work with it.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you have to connect the SQL file to pycharm, but to simplified the Big explanation here there's a video that explained you how to connect it